# pygame.error: video system not initialized python code error

Tags: python, pygame

After running this code, I got an error:

```
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

My code:

```
import sys
import pygame
def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
# Start the main loop for the game.
while True:
    # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

Can anyone help me and explain what this error means and how to rectify it?

Comment: welcome stackoveflow . read this doc : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for know how to ask question in stackoveflow

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised because `pygame.event.get` is called without an initialized display (`pygame.display.set_mode`). The problem is that your while loop is not indented correctly, so it is executed before the `run_game` function is called. The loop should be inside of the `run_game` function.

```
import sys
import pygame


def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code:

```
run_game()
```

before `while` statment`